# Tzaar Baalei Chaim

Tags: halacha, riddle

When according to Halacha you are obligated to be Metzaer Baalei Chaim?

Answer (score 5):

- When a king dies, his horses are hamstrung (Avodah Zara 11a)
- Animals used by idolators (Avodah Zara 13a)
- Hekdeishos, Charamim and Arachin (various types of consecrated animals) B'zman Hazeh (nowadays, in the absence of the Holy Temple) (Avodah Zara 13a)
- Chataos Ha-Meisos (Temurah 15b)

(Already dealt with here on Mi Yodeya... see [Why must Chata'os Ha-meisos be treated so harshly?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70/why-must-chataos-ha-meisos-be-treated-so-harshly))

Answer (score 1):

When doing Shluach Haken

Comment: If the Mishna in Brachos clearly sees Shiluah HaKen as an act of mercy (albeit not Hashem's mercy) then how can you write that it is an example of Tza'ar Baalei Hayim?

Comment: I think there is Halachic litriture about if the eggs not being needed not doing Shiluch hAKEN

Answer (score 0):

When your friend has an animal that needs unloading and your enemy has an animal that needs to be loaded, you are supposed to help your enemy first even though the animal that needs unloading is in pain.